# React card icon display

Tags: reactjs

a bit of help here if possible. I am creating a team card let's call it. I have a `.json`file with data. Problem is, what shall I do if one of the team members doesn't have a facebook account let's say...then I don't want the font awesome to be shown. Thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import teamData from '../components/data/teamInfo.json';

const TeamCard =({data})=>{
  const imgStyles = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "250px",
    borderRadius: "20px"
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="cardInner">
          <div className="card-front">
            <img src={data.image} alt="" style={imgStyles}/> 
            <div className="fontImg"><i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></div>
          </div>
          
          <div className="card-back"> 
              <h2>{data.name}<br/><span>{data.title}</span></h2>
              <p>{data.hobbies}</p>
              <div className="social-icons">
                  <a href={data.linkedIn}><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                  <a href={data.facebookId}><i className="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

const TeamCards =()=>{

  return (
    <div className="aboutUS">
      <div className="titleAbout">
        <h1>Meet the <span>team</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div className="teamIteration">
        {teamData && teamData.map((e, key) => {
          return (
            <TeamCard
              data={e}
              key={key} 
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TeamCards;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which parts exactly do you want to hide if they don't have a fb account?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add condition to check if person has facebokId.

```
<div className="social-icons">
  data.linkedIn && (<a href={data.linkedIn}><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>)
  data.facebookId && (<a href={data.facebookId}><i className="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>)
</div>
```

Comment: I know I have to add condition, but what you wrote there will still display all icons + data.linkedIn &&

Comment: if user does not have facebookId, which part of your code do you want to hide ?
<img src={data.image} alt="" style={imgStyles}/>  

and you in your .json file, if user does not have facebookId, I assume it is either null or '' string ?

Comment: This isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary function `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false` that only renders the component if `data.facebookId` is true in `state`

```
const component = ({ data.facebookId.state }) => (
  <div>
    {isTrue ? 
      (
           <a href={data.linkedIn}><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
         <a href={data.facebookId}><i className="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>

      ) : (

         <a href={data.facebookId}><i className="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>
      )}

  </div>
)
```